Glue job with Bedrock not running in parallel
I am writing a Glue job to process a pyspark dataframe using Bedrock which was recently added to boto3. The job will get sentiment from a text field in the dataframe using one of the LLMs in Bedrock, in this case Claude Instant. I created a UDF for this.
@F.udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def get_sentiment_score_udf(text):
    bedrock = boto3.client('bedrock-runtime', region_name='us-east-1')

    prompt = f"""
        Please predict the overall sentiment score in integer from the following text. 
        Positive 1, negative -1, and neutral 0. Only output the score, don't provide any text. {text}.
    """

    prompt_config = {
        "anthropic_version": "bedrock-2023-05-31",
        "max_tokens": 4096,
        "messages": [
            {
                "role": "user",
                "content": [
                    {"type": "text", "text": prompt},
                ],
            }
        ],
    }

    body = json.dumps(prompt_config)

    #"anthropic.claude-instant-v1", "anthropic.claude-3-sonnet-20240229-v1:0"
    model_id = MODEL_ID
    accept = "application/json"
    content_type = "application/json"

    response = bedrock.invoke_model(
        body=body, modelId=model_id, accept=accept, contentType=content_type
    )
    response_body = json.loads(response.get("body").read())

    result = response_body.get("content")[0].get("text")
    score = 0
    try:
        score = int(result)
    except:
        pass
    return score

voc_df = spark.read.parquet(f'{s3_path}')

voc_df = voc_df.withColumn('Senti', get_sentiment_score_udf('Text'))

However when I run it with 10 workers (40 DPUs), it didn't seem to run on any of the workers. See the screenshot of job metrics below

I have been using UDFs for ETL jobs in the same fashion and it always worked. This is the first time I am using boto3 and bedrock in a Glue job though. I think something between boto and spark is stopping the job run in parallel. I am using botocore 1.34.138 and Glue 4.0 (spark 3.3). What is the correct way to run bedrock with spark?
